# Did anyone has been recently hired by [redacted scammer name]?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency

Did anyone has been recently hired by [scammer name redacted] as J. payment Associate for converting money transfers to Bitcoin?

We did contact the Florida corporation department to verify if the company is not a fake company, and the state of Florida confirmed that the company exists, and the company is active. However, after 3 transactions, our bank informed us that those transactions have been reported as fraudulent.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You are, or are going to be, scammed. Walk away now.

Comment: You were probably not hired by Crypto Coki Financial, but rather by a scammer pretending to be them.

Comment: There is no such job as transferring payments from one method to another, using your own systems / accounts / name. This is always a scam.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that your contact with this company uses a gmail/yahoo/msn/whatever email address rather than one at the company's actual web domain or anything resembling the contact details they have on their 'Contact Us' page ... ? Do you not find that in the least bit suspicious ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_mule